# SDL Web 8.5 Support remember the last hyperlink location?

Tags: gui-extensions, web8.5

We have new requirement for our hyperlink customization with "User select last hyperlink location"

**Steps for requirement:**

1. Open a Component with a Rich text field
2. Select some text in the RTF field and click the **Hyperlink** button in the ribbon bar
3. Select **Type: Component** and click the Browse button to choose a Component via the treeview
4. Recreate the scenario from step 2 and 3, and the treeview should be opening on the location of the last selected Component in step 3

Currently in step 4, it will reopen the treeview in the last location which was openend when selecting a Component on a Page, and it has forgotten the location which was selected in step 3.

Looking for solutions and ideas for this requirement.

Comment: You tagged your question with `gui-extensions`, so am I gathering correctly you want to add this behavior through a UI extension and are asking if that is possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved add one more line in filter **("SubType: $const.ComponentSubType.COMPONENT")**

```
filter = {
                        conditions:
                    {
                        ItemTypes: [$const.ItemType.COMPONENT],
                        ShowNewItems: true,
                        BasedOnSchema: [linkSchemaId],          
                        SubType: $const.ComponentSubType.COMPONENT
                    }
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Remembering the last location in a treeview has been implemented a while ago when selecting a Component in a Page (I think that was before Web 8 already), but it seems this is not respected when choosing a Component Link in a Rich Text field.

I woudn't know how you can add this type of behavior yourself, unless you are building your own treeview (which is not so trivial). So best I can suggest is that you suggest this as an idea on https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/sdl_web_ideas/i/sdl-web-ideas (so it can be considered for a future release)